# AES_DECRYPT with Codeigniters Active Record

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, encryption, aes

Hi has anyone had experience with using AES_DECRYPT and codeigniters active record. I've tried using the following line:

`$query = $this->db->select("AES_DECRYPT(testing,'$key') as testing");`

but continue to get an sql syntax error. I've tried using a manual standard sql string which works but would prefer to stick with active record if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeIgniter is trying to escape that, and it has no idea how to.  Add `FALSE` as the 2nd parameter to tell it not to escape it.

```
// We need to escape this value before the query
$key = $this->db->escape($key);
// Tell CodeIgniter not to escape this
$this->db->select("AES_DECRYPT(testing, $key) as testing", FALSE);
```

Comment: can't believe I missed that, I've turned off the escaping for the insert already. I haven't tried it yet but hopefully it will work and i'll mark your answer. thanks